# How do I convert an integer to the corresponding words in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way in Objective-C on iOS to spell out an integer number as text?

For example, if I have

```
NSInteger someNumber = 11242043;
```

I would like to know some function so that would return a string similar to "eleven million two hundred forty two thousand forty three."

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Apple has a lot of handy formatting functionality built in for many data types. Called a "formatter," they can convert objects to/from string representations.

For your case, you will be using NSNumberFormatter, but if you have an integer you need to convert it to an NSNumber first.  See below example.

```
NSInteger anInt = 11242043;
NSString *wordNumber;

//convert to words
NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:anInt]; //needs to be NSNumber!
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
wordNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberValue];
NSLog(@"Answer: %@", wordNumber);
// Answer: eleven million two hundred forty-two thousand forty-three
```

If you'd like to learn more about formatters:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Formatter.html

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm!

Comment: `@(anInt)` would have been a slightly more compact way to write it; based on a quick test the NSNumberFormatter also isn't perfect at localisation (despite being in British English, I got hyphenated versions of forty and no 'and'), but it's probably still a million times better than building your own.

Answer (score 37):

Power of extension for Swift 5

```
import Foundation

public extension Int {
  var asWord: String? {
    let numberValue = NSNumber(value: self)
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
    return formatter.string(from: numberValue)
  }
}

var value = 2
if let valueAsWord = value.asWord {
    //do something with your worded number here
    print("value worded = \(valueAsWord)")
} else {
    print("could not word value :(")
}
```

Note: Edited to protect against `formatter.string(from:` returning nil which is highly not likely, but still possible.

Output:
value worded = two

Comment: This won't work for lakhs (i.e. if 1,00,000 then it returns "One Hundred Thousand")

Answer (score 10):

From the docs:

> `NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle`
>
> Specifies a spell-out format; for example, “23” becomes “twenty-three”.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> Declared in NSNumberFormatter.h.

As your question isn't very specific, I won't post full-fledged code source either.

Comment: What if I need 23 to be spelled as "twenty third"?

Answer (score 8):

With Swift 5 / iOS 12.2, `NumberFormatter` has a `numberStyle` property that can be set with value `NumberFormatter.Style.spellOut`. [`spellOut`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/style/spellout) has the following declaration:

```
case spellOut = 5
```

> A style format in which numbers are spelled out in the language defined by the number formatter locale.

> For example, in the en_US locale, the number 1234.5678 is represented as one thousand two hundred thirty-four point five six seven eight; in the fr_FR locale, the number 1234.5678 is represented as mille deux cent trente-quatre virgule cinq six sept huit.

> This style is supported for most user locales. If this style doesn't support the number formatter locale, the en_US locale is used as a fallback.

---

The Playground code below shows how to convert an integer to a spell-out text using `NumberFormatter` `spellOut` style:

```
import Foundation

let integer = 2018

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.spellOut

let spellOutText = formatter.string(for: integer)!
print(spellOutText) // prints: two thousand eighteen
```

Comment: This won't work for lakhs (i.e. if 1,00,000 then it returns "One Hundred Thousand")

Answer (score 6):

We can do this in swift like this.

```
   let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
   formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle. SpellOutStyle
   println("\(identifier) \(formatter.stringFromNumber(1234.5678))")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below function to convert an integer to words using swift native number style.

```
func toWords<N>(number: N) -> String? {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

    switch number {
    case is Int, is UInt, is Float, is Double:
        return formatter.string(from: number as! NSNumber)
    case is String:
        if let number = Double(number as! String) {
            return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: number))
        }
    default:
        break
    }
    return nil
}

print(toWords(number: 12312))

print(toWords(number: "12312"))
```

Answer (score 1):

For my own reference, this is @moca's answer, but ready for use:

```
- (NSString *) spellInt:(int)number {
    NSNumber *numberAsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:number];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
    return [formatter stringFromNumber:numberAsNumber];
}
```

Note: This is using ARC.