# Change numbers to text iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, numbers

I am not sure how to explain this but I need something like this and I'm not quite sure how to do it. I have a textfield where the user enters a number. For example "200". I got a label that must show "Two Hundred"(The number entered in Words )

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance sorry for my bad english

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250433/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-the-corresponding-words-in-objective-c

Comment: This is a duplicate.  Follow the link by @AnthonyBlake and delete this question.

Comment: @RoboticCat You can't delete a question with answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
 //textField.text is 200
 NSInteger someInt = [textField.text integerValue];
 NSString *numberWord;

 NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:someInt];
 NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
 numberWord = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberValue];

 NSLog(@"numberWord= %@", numberWord); // Answer: two hundred

 yourLabel.text = numberWord;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNumberFormatter) It can convert an NSNumber into its word representation.

```
NSNumber* number = @100;
NSString* textNumber;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
textNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something totally different. A bit more complex and weird, but you can fiddle around with it if you seek more manual control over the output. This is set up to serve a value up to 100,000 (to demonstrate a conditional set up).

Have fun:

```
int theInteger = 1,123;

int convert1000 = 0;
int convert100 = 0;
int convert10 = 0;
int convert1 = 0;

NSString * wordThousand = @"Thousand";
NSString * wordHundred = @"Hundred";

NSArray *wordsArraySingleDigit = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Zero",@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",nil];

NSArray *wordsArrayDoubleDigit = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ten",@"Eleven",@"Twelve",...,@"Ninety Eight", @"Ninety Nine",nil];



convert1000 = (theInteger - (theInteger % 1000))/1000;
convert100 = ((theInteger - (convert1000 * 1000)) - ((theInteger - (convert1000 * 1000)) % 100))/100;
convert10 = ((theInteger - (convert1000 *1000)-(convert100 *100)) - ((theInteger -(convert1000 *1000) - (convert100 *100)) % 10))/10;
convert1 = (theInteger - (convert1000 *1000)-(convert100 *100) - (convert10 *10));

if (theInteger > = 10000 && < 100000){
    NSString * convertedThousand = [wordsArrayDoubleDigit objectAtIndex : convert1000];
    convertedThousand = [NSString stringWithFormat: @“%@ %@“,convertedThousand,wordThousand];
    NSLog (convertedThousand);
 }

if (theInteger >= 1000 && <= 10000){
    NSString * convertedThousand = [wordsArraySingleDigit objectAtIndex : convert1000];
    convertedThousand = [NSString stringWithFormat: @“%@ %@“,convertedThousand,wordThousand];
    NSLog (convertedThousand);
}


NSString * convertedHundred = [wordsArraySingleDigit objectAtIndex : convert100];
convertedHundred = [NSString stringWithFormat: @“%@ %@“, convertedHundred,wordHundred];
NSLog (convertedHundred);

NSString * convertedTen = [wordsArraySingleDigit objectAtIndex : convert10];
convertedTen = [NSString stringWithFormat: @“%@“, convertedTen];
NSLog (convertedTen);


NSString *convertedOne = [wordsArraySingleDigit objectAtIndex : convert1];
NSLog (convertedOne);
```

Hope this helps or gives you a starting point for an alternative approach.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should account for every possibility and make a set of IF statements, for example, if the first digit of the number is 3, write "three", if the number has 4 digits, display "thousands"... of course you can organize your code to make the process easy.