# How can I show label text dynamically?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am using an UICollectionViewController in which I shown an different images, but I also want to Add labels for every image and label should show the text dynamically.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  
   cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

SSCollectionViewCell *cell = (SSCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

int imageNumber = indexPath.row % 10;

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%d.jpeg",imageNumber]];

cell.myLabel.text =  @"Hello";

return cell;

}
```

Comment: what would be your dynamic text on label?

Comment: In cell.myLabel.text I would like to print one for image 1 , two for image 2 and so on depending on total number of images

Comment: I think that this post solves your problem:

[number to text][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250433/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-the-corresponding-words-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to print the image number to your text label then

```
cell.myLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",imageNumber];
```

this will do

Comment: Bingo , what if instead of printing imageNumber I want to print text like one, two and so on , will i have to make array for that.

Comment: Yes, make a array and you can print them based on index.