# What is the best way to convert numbers into the corresponding words?

Tags: swift

```
let numberDict = [ 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four", 5: "five"]
print(numberDict[5] ?? "don't know")
```

What is the best way to convert numbers into the corresponding words?

Comment: In an infinite amount of other ways, e.g. add newlines whereever, rename variables etc. Honestly: what is that code doing? If you are looking for improving existing code you should take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34924856/1187415

Comment: Updated the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Foundation library has a built-in `NumberFormatter` class which can spell out numbers:

```
let number = 1
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
let numberString = formatter.string(from: number)
```

In the above example `numberString` is "one" (optional). Please note that `NumberFormatter` is locale-aware.

Comment: nice one.. reusing existing technologies.. upvote from me

Comment: Good one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go crazy, you can do it using an enum (but in a way, it goes back to `switch`):

```
enum Number: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case one = 1
    case two = 2
    case three = 3
    case four = 4
    case five = 5

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .one: return "one"
        case .two: return "two"
        case .three: return "three"
        case .four: return "four"
        case .five: return "five"
        }
    }
}

let number = 3
let enumedNumber: Number? = Number(rawValue: number)

print(enumedNumber ?? "Don't know")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to define the names by your own, the shortest solution would be

```
let array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
let number = 1
print(number > 0 && number <= array.count ? array[number - 1] : "unknown")
```

If you prefer a crazy approach you could use

```
print(NSLocalizedString(number, comment: ""))
```

With a `Localizable.strings` file containing

```
"1" = "one";
"2" = "two";
"3" = "three";
"4" = "four";
"5" = "five";
```

Comment: yes. this is my original requirement. I was just using one, two, three as an example. Thanks.