# How to convert number to words in swift by using func

Tags: swift

Given the integer 'number' in the range of 0 ..<< 1000, print the number as a word.
For example, given:  let number : Int = 125
output should be one-hundred and twenty-five

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an integer to the corresponding words in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250433/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-the-corresponding-words-in-objective-c)

Comment: You can use `NumberFormatter` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NumberFormatter pretty effectively :) Here's example

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
let number = 12355532
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
let numberAsWord = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number))
print(numberAsWord)
```

You could also extend NSNumber to do this behind the scenes like this

```
public extension NSNumber {
    var spelledOut: String? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is far from effective. Note that this will create a new NumberFormatter every time you call this property.

Comment: Cool, is that all you have, or are you gonna actually make an improvement suggestion? Not intended to be the most efficient solution, just a quick and dirty approach. Plenty of things you can do to make it better. Create the number formatter a single time and reuse, for instance.

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68475876/2303865)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid creating a Number Formatter every time you call this property you can create a static formatter. You can also make the computed property generic to support all numeric types:

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    static let spelled: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension Numeric {
    var spelledOut: String? { NumberFormatter.spelled.string(for: self) }
}
```

---

```
let integer = 1234
let integerSpelled = integer.spelledOut  // "one thousand two hundred thirty-four"

let double = 123.4
let doubleSpelled = double.spelledOut  // "one hundred twenty-three point four"
```